# react-native: Nested callbacks how to bind method

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

nested callback function I tried with arrow function, bind function as well but function is not triggering after getting facebook access token I need to call api with **this.handleApiCalls** here my code snippet

```
    const FBSDK = require('react-native-fbsdk')
const {
    LoginButton,
    AccessToken
 } = FBSDK

 class LoginScreen extends React.Component {
        constructor () {
            super(props)
        }

        handleApiCalls = () => {
            alert("handle the api calls");
        }

  render () {
     return  <View style={{justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center'}}>
                            <LoginButton
                                publishPermissions={['publish_actions']}
                                onLoginFinished={
    // first call back
                                    (error, result) => {
                                      if (error) {

                                        console.log('error:', error);
                                      } else if (result.isCancelled) {
                                        alert('login is cancelled.')
                                        console.log('login is cancelled:', result);
                                      } else {
    // second callback

    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then((data) => {
        console.log('Access_Token:'+data.accessToken.toString())

    // ================ how to call this function ===============
        this.handleApiCalls 

      })


                                      }
                                    }
                                  }
                          onLogoutFinished={() => alert('logout.')}/>
                        </View>
        }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if `console.log('Access_Token:'+data.accessToken.toString())` is working then just change `this.handleApiCalls` to `this.handleApiCalls()` to invoke it.